# Twitter Search API: Getting error 32 could not authenticate you with specific searches but not every search

Tags: python-3.x, twitter

I'm using python3 to send a request to the Twitter Search API. I'm testing these requests in Postman, and then using the code snippit generator to copy and paste into my editor to run like so:

```
url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=twitter"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="",oauth_token="",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1613517432",oauth_nonce="x",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_body_hash="",oauth_signature=""',
  'Cookie': 'personalization_id=""; lang=en; guest_id='
}


twitter_response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

The requests work just fine in Postman. But in my script, the request only works when the query parameter for the URL is "nasa". If I change it to anything else, I get error 32 Could not authenticate.

Is there some quirk about Python I don't know about when it comes to the Twitter Search API? Any guidance would be helpful here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you’re copying and pasting the OAuth headers from the Twitter Dev docs instead of calculating them with every new query. I think the docs use NASA as an example search query.

Comment: No, I'm using all of my own OAuth keys (which aren't being displayed here) and the header is being generated in Postman with every new request I make. Like I said, these requests work in Postman and return the correct response in the API client. But when I use the same code and change the search query from NASA (which is the example search query in the docs), to anything else, I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a way around this by using the Tweepy API wrapper, which solved my OAuth issues. The headers weren't getting formatted properly for the request.